# Set default value in AutoCompleteBox in lightswitch application

Tags: .net, silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have 2 tables (lets say orders and items) orders has foreign key references to Items  table. Items has a column ItemType of type string, ItemType bound to a choose List with items TypeA, typeB, TypeC...

I have create a screen (list details screen ) for Orders and Items,Orders are rendered in RowLayout and items are rendered in data grid inside row layout. Item type in bound to Autocompletebox.

Everything is working as expected Item type is getting populated from associated list.

Now I want to set AutoCompleteBox with default value Let say TypeA whenever I create a new row in the data grid, I tried setting ItemType property in Items_changed event, when action is  Add(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add) and tried couple of other options but no sucess.

I was able to set value of simple properties in Items_changed event but not able to set ItemType.

Can someone let me know how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relatively simple to do.  In the _Created() method of your Items entity, add a line of code to assign the default type value.  I prefer to use look-up tables to entity-local enumerations, so I will usually do this via a LINQ query.  Assuming the following entitie collections:

- Orders
- OrderItems
- OrderItemTypes

My code-behind for the Created() method on OrderItems would look something like this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.LightSwitch;
namespace LightSwitchApplication
{
    public partial class OrderItem
    {

        partial void OrderItem_Created()
        {
            this.Quantity = 0;
            if ((from OrderItemType oit in DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.OrderItemTypes
                 where oit.IsDefaultOrderItemType == true
                 select oit).Count() > 0)
            {
                this.OrderItemType = (from OrderItemType oit in DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.OrderItemTypes
                                      where oit.IsDefaultOrderItemType == true
                                      select oit).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note the query uses an IsDefaultOrderItemType field on the OrderItemType entity to determine which OrderItemTypes entry to use as the default.  You could also use OrderItemType.TypeName or whatever descriptor you've used for the OrderItemType as your selector in the query if you prefer.

Hope that helps. :)

PS: Don't set values programmatically in the _Changed() handler unless you want to override data entry!